# Calling jQuery function from from js

Tags: jquery

I've written a Simple function in Javascript which calls a jQuery function 
the problem is Why do I need to click button to get the toggle effect

html

```
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="toggle()" />
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle()
{
    new_toggle();
}
</script>
```

jQuery

```
$(function new_toggle2(){
        $('#toggle').click(function(){

    $('#p1').toggle(); // Simple <p> and <h1> tags
            $('#h').toggle();   
        });
    new_toggle = new_toggle2;
});
```

Comment: Because you have specified onclick="toggle()" ???

Comment: What do you want to call the toggle function, instead of clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will be sufficient for click event.

HTML:

```
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle" />
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('#toggle').click(function(){

            $('#p1').toggle(); // Simple <p> and <h1> tags
            $('#h').toggle();   
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this code with you:

```
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="toggle()" />
```

The `toggle()` is the function, which should be initiated. That function is *bound* to the `<input>` tag with the help of `onclick=` attribute. The onclick event is used to execute a JavaScript when an element is clicked.

If you want to trigger that function on page load, then a small change is required. The `toggle()` function should be called when the document loads.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little bit confused about it...

Remove:

```
onclick="toggle()"
```

and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle()
{
    new_toggle();
}
</script>
```

And write just this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#toggle').click(function(){

        $('#p1').toggle();
        $('#h').toggle();   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You !! Very much man .... A slight change in jQuery's Code n I got the result ..Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Reading a lot into your question! - If you want your toggle function to fire on page load, rather than when you click the button change your function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            new_toggle2();
    }
</script>
```